# AWS CDK - Can't access ALB through Cloudfront domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I'm trying to deploy a fairly basic Nodejs CRUD API to AWS using AWS-CDK. The service runs in a docker container and I'm deploying it to an ECS Fargate cluster behind an ALB. I also have a domain in Route53 that I'm trying to use.

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to access the ALB through the domain. I can access the ALB directly using its default AWS DNS (XXXXX.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/) over HTTP, but I get 504 timeouts when I attempt to access it through the domain.

I'm pretty new to AWS and CDK, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. Any advice or recommended resources/examples would be much appreciated. Here's my CDK code:

```js
import { Stack, StackProps } from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import * as Cloudfront from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudfront";
import * as CloudfrontOrigins from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-cloudfront-origins";
import * as Route53 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53";
import * as Route53Targets from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53-targets";
import * as ACM from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-certificatemanager";
import * as EC2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";
import * as ECS from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs";
import * as EcsPatterns from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ecs-patterns";

interface Props extends StackProps {
  domainName: string;
  dockerDir: string;
}

export class AppStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, { domainName, dockerDir, ...rest }: Props) {
    super(scope, id, rest);

    const hostedZone = Route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, `${id}_Zone`, {
      domainName,
    });

    const vpc = new EC2.Vpc(this, `${id}_Vpc`, { maxAzs: 2 });
    const cluster = new ECS.Cluster(this, `${id}_Ec2Cluster`, { vpc });
    cluster.addCapacity(`${id}_DefaultAutoScalingGroup`, {
      instanceType: EC2.InstanceType.of(
        EC2.InstanceClass.T3,
        EC2.InstanceSize.MICRO
      ),
      minCapacity: 1,
      maxCapacity: 3,
    });
    const certificate = new ACM.DnsValidatedCertificate(
      this,
      `${id}_SiteCertificate`,
      {
        domainName,
        hostedZone,
        region: "us-east-1",
      }
    );
  
    const fargateService = new EcsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
      this,
      `${id}_FargateLoadBalancedService`,
      {
        cluster,
        desiredCount: 1,
        publicLoadBalancer: true,
        taskImageOptions: {
          image: ECS.ContainerImage.fromAsset(dockerDir),
          containerPort: 8000,
          environment: {
            PORT: '8000',
          },
        },
      }
    );
  
    const distribution = new Cloudfront.Distribution(
      this,
      `${id}_SiteDistribution`,
      {
        certificate,
        domainNames: [domainName],
        minimumProtocolVersion: Cloudfront.SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2021,
        defaultBehavior: {
          origin: new CloudfrontOrigins.HttpOrigin(
            fargateService.loadBalancer.loadBalancerDnsName
          ),
          compress: false,
          cachePolicy: Cloudfront.CachePolicy.CACHING_DISABLED,
          allowedMethods: Cloudfront.AllowedMethods.ALLOW_ALL,
        },
      }
    );
  
  
    new Route53.ARecord(this, `${id}_SiteAliasRecord`, {
      recordName: domainName,
      target: Route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
        new Route53Targets.CloudFrontTarget(distribution)
      ),
      zone: hostedZone,
    });
  }
}
```

And this class gets created in my bin/infra.ts file:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import "source-map-support/register";
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import * as path from "path";
import { AppStack } from "../lib/AppStack";

const appId = `MyApp`;
const app = new cdk.App();

new AppStack(app, `${appId}Stack`, {
  dockerDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "api"), // contains the Dockerfile
  domainName: 'mydomain.com',
  env: {
    account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
    region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
  },
});
```

And here's the Dockerfile in case it's useful.

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

ENV NODE_ENV build

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i

COPY --chown=node:node . .
RUN npm run build \
    && npm prune --production

# ---

FROM node:16-alpine

ENV PORT 8000
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add curl for healthcheck
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/node_modules/ ./node_modules/
COPY --from=builder --chown=node:node /home/node/dist/ ./dist/

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["node", "dist/main.js"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl -f http://localhost:8000/api/healthcheck || exit 1
```

Why am I getting 504 errors when I access my service through my domain? Or where can I look to get a better idea of what I'm missing?

Comment: One thing to mention is that since you configure the CloudFront distribution with the domain and certificate, that should already create the record. You don't need to create it yourself. Did you manage to get it to work in the meantime?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? @SimpleJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CloudFront talks HTTPS (port 443) to its origins by default. An ALB (regardless of whether created explicitly or implicitly by the `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` construct) listens on HTTP (port 80) by default unless explicitly set up for HTTPS.
As your ALB is not configured to listen on HTTPS, CloudFront attempts to talk HTTPS to an ALB that only listens on HTTP.

To fix that, set `origin.protocolPolicy` to `OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY`, which instructs CloudFront to talk HTTP to your ALB. Please note that the below code uses CDK v2 and also, I've used `LoadBalancerV2Origin` over `HttpOrigin`, although both should work the same.

```
const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
  vpc,
  internetFacing: true,
});
new cloudfront.Distribution(this, 'myDist', {
  defaultBehavior: {
    new origins.LoadBalancerV2Origin(loadBalancer, {
      protocolPolicy: cloudfront.OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY,
    })
  },
});
```